# Oh no - Scrapy CSS selector used several times on a product detail page?

Tags: css, scrapy, css-selectors, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape products (not something surprising) - but honestly, defining the CSS selector for the product descriptions that works on any product page gives me a headache.

I look for the selector that defines the product description from the following link:

https://www.onlinebaufuchs.de/Werkzeug-Technik/Elektrowerkzeuge/Akku-Geraete/Akku-Schlagschrauber/Guede-Akku-Schlagschrauber-BSS-18-1-4-Zoll-0-Akkuschrauber-ohne-Akku-Ladegeraet::7886.html

The selector is:

```
#inner > div > div.col-lg-12-full.col-md-12-full > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(12)
```

Alternatively, the selector can be:

```
div.pd_description:nth-of-type(6)
```

But sometimes the selector changes:

https://www.onlinebaufuchs.de/Werkzeug-Technik/Elektrowerkzeuge/Akku-Geraete/18-Volt-Lithium-Ionen-Akkusystem/Guede-Ladegeraet-LG-18-05-0-5-A-Aufladegeraet-fuer-diverse-Guede-Akku-Werkzeuge::7852.html

Here is the selector:

```
#inner > div > div.col-lg-12-full.col-md-12-full > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(11)
```

Alternatively, the selector can be:

```
div.pd_description:nth-of-type(5)
```

When I look at the source code, the section of product description is defined with

```
.pd_description
```

But it's too general and used often in the source code for other sections too.

I can't figure out how to solute this problem.

My spider runs correctly, but from product to product i get empty descriptions (cause of my described issue).

```
def parse_product(self, response):
  for product in response.css("body"):
     yield {
     "brand": product.css('div.pd_inforow:nth-of-type(4) span::text').extract(),
     "item_name": product.css("h1::text').extract(),
     "description": product.css('#inner > div > div.col-lg-12-full.col-md-12-full > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(12)').extract_first
```

Why don't I match the product description with a CSS selector on all pages?

Answer (score 2):

Using XPath selector (get `div` with class equal to `pd_description` that contains `h4` with text `Produktbeschreibung`):

```
product.xpath('.//div[@class="pd_description"][h4[.="Produktbeschreibung"]]').get()
```

Comment: You made my day @gangabass

I had tried something similar, but only addressed the div class attribute selector and got the same, useless result again.

I tried:

('*//div[@class="pd_description"]').get()

I hadn't noticed the h4 tag at all - especially with the right keyword, which is theoretically "always" included on every single product page. ‍♂️

Thank you - you really put me on the right way